# Swapping nested dictionary access

Tags: movement

In python if you have a nested dictionary, accessing elements will look like this:

```
dict["key1"]["key2"]
```

How would I go about swapping the two keys the fastest? Nothing really comes to my mind other than something like `di[wwdi["p1bbp`.

Also just out of curiosity, if the construct is `dict.key1.key2` are there different/better solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What comes to my mind is

```
da[%p
```

Using `%` is less important. Just make sure to cut *the whole* `[expr]` and put it back where appropriate.

> if the construct is dict.key1.key2

Something like moving to the *left* dot then cutting the key with `dt.`. And then `ep` or something like that to put it back. If you have a plugin like `wellle/targets` then you can cut it with `da.` instead.

Comment: I have no idea why I didn't think of just cutting the entire expression ... :D Very easy and fast, thanks!